# Powershell command required to strip ID/Passport No's from columns delimited text file

Tags: powershell

Have text File as per below;

New to Powershell so need guidance here.

INPUT TXT

```
membercode|id_number|passportnumber
BED_ODG0001|5007160081|
PF-000552516|7605430081|
PF-000704976|0385084|
PF-000678375||EP3800795
```

Need ONLY the ID_Number Column, but if there is no value move the Passportnumber value into the column.

REQUIRED OUTPUT TXT

```
5007160081
7605430081
0385084
EP3800795
```

Comment: What have you tried, and how has what you've tried failed? Ideally, you should provide a [MCVE] of what you've tried, and include specific information on how it failed, with error messages and/or erroneous output. [SO] is not a code-writing service; the best questions are those which provide useful information so that those who answer can guide you to devising your own correct answer. See [Ask] a Good Question.

Comment: Having said the above, I commend to your attention the [`Import-CSV`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0) cmdlet (available since PowerShell 3.0), with special attention to the `-Delimiter` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a bit bored waiting on this, so here you go:

Have a look at the [Import-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-6) cmdlet.
Basically, your input txt file looks like a valid CSV file, including field headers, where the fields are separated using a pipe-symbol `|`.

Using `Import-Csv` in combination with parameter `-Delimiter`, it is really easy to load the data as an array of objects.
Every field in the file will be represented in these objects as properties that have names as defined in the file headers.

```
$inputFile  = 'YOUR PATH AND FILENAME TO THE INPUT TXT FILE'
$outputFile = 'YOUR PATH AND FILENAME FOR THE OUTPUT TXT FILE'

# load the data from the CSV as an array of objects into a variable
$data = Import-Csv -Path $inputFile -Delimiter '|'

# loop through the elements of this array (the data rows in the file).
# inside the loop, the automatic variable '$_' is an object representing 
# one element in the array (~~> row in the file)
$data | ForEach-Object {
    # output the field 'id_number' or if that is not there, use the field 'passportnumber'
    # and write it to the $outputFile file
    if ($_.id_number) { $_.id_number } else { $_.passportnumber }
} | Set-Content -Path $outputFile
```

Result:

> ```
> 5007160081
> 7605430081
> 0385084
> EP3800795
> ```

Comment: This worked flawlessly, I appreciate it. I couldnt respond to the earlier questions about what I tried (long weekend in SA). Essentially, I was running a powershell command, to run a VBS Script importing the file into Excel, running a Macro that trimmed the file and then exported into txt. Then I ran another powershell to trim as the txt file had spaces at the end of each rown, this LITERALLY fixed all those steps into one. I am truly appreciative. Thank you.